# Как реализовать эффект появления фото?

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Увидел эффект с фото, но ради профессионального интереса не стал открывать "просмотр кода" и решил сам реализовать, то что на скриншоте :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне удалось, так реализовать, как в примере ниже, но мне кажется, что решение не очень красивое!    Можно ли это, как-то по другому сделать?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #E3DFD2
}

svg {
  background: url('http://www.frombearcreek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/2016_07_15_Rule-Five-Friday-1-1024x683.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 30vmin auto;
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: font-size .4s ease-out;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
}

svg:hover text {
  transition: font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 600px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
      <defs>
        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="49">
          <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
          <text x="20" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">s</text>
          <text x="25" id="ltrV" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">e</text>
          <text x="30" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">e</text>
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.6" fill="#222000"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: «Можно ли это, как-то по другому сделать?» — эм, открыть просмотр кода? :D Я немного не понял, чем просмотр кода будет принципиально отличаться от просмотра ответов здесь)

Comment: @andreymal хм... замечание принято ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот более чистая версия:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #E3DFD2
}

svg {
  background: url('http://www.frombearcreek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/2016_07_15_Rule-Five-Friday-1-1024x683.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 30vmin auto;
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: font-size .4s ease-out;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

svg:hover text {
  transition: font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 600px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
      <text x="25" text-anchor="middle" y="50" color="#fff">see</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.6" fill="#222000"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: я тоже думал объеденить see в одно слово ... вариант !

Comment: нужен совет по другому вопросу : сможешь помочь ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, конечно могу

Comment: вот скажи если ли способ кроссбраузерно перевернуть текст что бы он начинался в низу с права ? https://jsfiddle.net/m83d2ju2/8/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ты имеешь ввиду перевернуть на 180 градусов?

Comment: нееет ! что бы он читалься не кк обычно и снизу вверх - примерно как арабы читают только writing-mode не такой результат даёт https://jsfiddle.net/m83d2ju2/10/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, хм, есть костыльные способы, но к твоему варианту вряд ли подойдут, c `writing-mode` нельзя добиться такого результата, насколько я знаю

Comment: да я знаю , конкретно не работает :  sideways-lr для writing-mode точнее он работает только в лисе и всё

Comment: а на svg это можно сделать ? динамично ? текст всегда меняется

Comment: @МаксимЛенский интересное, свежее решение. На полном экране смотрится классно!.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ничего не нашёл по этому поводу, никогда не приходилось такое делать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT особенно девочка на фотке ваще атас ....

Answer (score 3):

У меня удалось так реализовать но мне кажется что решение не красивое ! 
Можно ли это как то по другому сделать?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #E3DFD2
}

svg {
  background: url('http://www.frombearcreek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/2016_07_15_Rule-Five-Friday-1-1024x683.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 30vmin auto;
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: font-size .4s ease-out;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial;
}

svg:hover text {
  transition: font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 600px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="49">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
      <text x="20" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">s</text>
      <text x="25" id="ltrV" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">e</text>
      <text x="30" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">e</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.6" fill="#222000"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

К изображению на фоне применена текстовая  маска со словом **`SVG`**, окрашенная в белый цвет   `fill="#fff"`

При наведении размер шрифта увеличивается и фоновое изображение становится полностью видимым

```
svg:hover text{
  transition:font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 300px;
```

Полный код:

```css
body,html{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;background:#E3DFD2}
svg{
  background:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  width:40vmin; height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin:30vmin auto;
}
text{
  font-size:10px;
  transition:font-size .4s ease-out;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:arial;
}
svg:hover text{
  transition:font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="49">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
      <text x="20" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">S</text>
      <text x="25" id="ltrV" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">V</text>
      <text x="30" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">G</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="1" fill="#E3DFD2"/>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/LGYBrQ)

Comment: что то в сниппете  ни чего нету ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский так опять тоже самое - `Edge` не любит SVG

Comment: я щас с оперы смотрю ... edge что то у меня тупить стал ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Привет! Вот скрин - открыл сниппет из-под браузера `Opera` https://i.stack.imgur.com/byca5.png правда на нем не видно эффекта наведения, но в живую есть. Кстати Максим какой командой гифки делаешь с экрана?

Comment: с гифами вообще не парюсь - записал экран faststone capture и потом в интернет "конвертировать wmv to gif " но когда я был в ubuntu там это автоматизировано в ffmpeg - в ubuntu это лучше работает

Comment: и да забыл скрин показать :https://cloud.mail.ru/public/AxLL/MVSEstmNP у меня в опере 0 , я плюсик поставил за старание но не видно ни чего вообще только фон

Comment: @МаксимЛенский может версии операционок и браузеров у нас разные. У меня вот такие https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKwAG.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75543/discussion-between---and-alexandr-tt).